# Assigning points based on length of list of list

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, if-statement

I was trying to figure out how to assign numbers to a certain point in a list based on how many items that there were left in a list.
For example:

```
def prizeHandout(prizeWinners):
    for x in range(len(prizeWinners)):
        if len(prizeWinners) == 24:
            prizeWinners[x][2] = (int(prize[0]))
        elif len(prizeWinners) == 12:
            prizeWinners[x][2] = (int(prize[1]))
        elif len(prizeWinners) == 6:
            prizeWinners[x][2] = (int(prize[2]))
    print(prizeWinners)
```

I have a global variable `'prize'` which is a list with the prizes [`10, 20, 30,....]`
The '`prizeWinners`' are in a list of list in this format `[[ab, 2, 0], [ba, 5, 0], [aa, 12, 0], .....]`
In the '`prizeWinners`' variable, the assignment of the '`prize`' should add on to the current space `[2]` and be added to the previous number if there was one.
Can't seem to get this working.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

```
def prizesFunction():
    with open('prizes.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        prizePoints = list(reader)
        first= [i[1] for i in prizePoints]
        second = [i[0] for i in prizePoints]
        third = [i[2] for i in prizePoints]
        fourth = [i[3] for i in prizePoints]

    choice = input('Enter your choice [0-4] : ')
    choice = int(choice)
    global prize
    if choice == 1:
        prize = first
        return prize
    elif choice == 2:
        prize =second
        return prize
    elif choice == 3:
        prize = third
        return prize
    elif choice == 4:
        prize = fourth
        return prize
```

Comment: What have you tried? What happens and what would you expect?

Comment: Hi there mrCarnivore, I would expect the output for one of the first to be [[ab, 2, 10], [ba, 5, 10], .....] Currently I am having the error 'TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment'  and have tried to change the types of the variables, but as they are lists I am unsure about what to try and change them to.

Comment: Please show us the exact code that leads to the problem (only the relevant parts!) and the exact error message in the question (you can edit it!)

Comment: I've just uploaded some more if that is of any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, since you are getting something out of this, I'll break it down again.  Although I'm pretty sure that I still don't understand, and therefore, can't solve your problem.  But, we can clean it up a bit.

I still don't like global variables.  You do what you want in your code for now, but I'm telling you that `global` is a keyword because it should only be used in extraordinary situations.  But, since you `return prize` and don't use it, before or after assignment I've replaced the global with a `return` value and added an assignment outside of the function.  Again, this is python, not C.  Everything is an object, and is generally passed by reference.  So it's OK to return things, and not modify in place.

The next thing that catches my attention is the list comprehensions for `first` through `fourth`.  Three things about this, first is that they are defined in a `with` block, which means that they potentially could be undefined if there is an error opening 'prizes.csv' So I initilize them as an empty list breofre the `with`.  Next, this list comprehension is a bit our of order in that `first` is the 2nd value and `second` is the 1st value, so I rearranged that.  Finally, why are you doing this exactly?  This will produce a list of values that represent the 1st through 4th columns of the input csv. 
If I had to guess, what this means is that you want to create the prize that is the column of the CSV.  At least the first 4 rows of that column, anyway.

So finally, your problem is a type error.  This is why you're really here.  The output of the csv.reader is a list of `str` and the values you want are `int` or possibly `float` values.  So, as I mentioned above, the safe way to read a string literal into a python value is to use the `ast.literal_eval()` function.  This can be accomplished in a couple of ways. I think that the best place in your code is in the list comprehension (I left them there just for this purpose).  You can see where I added the `ast.literal_eval()`, this function takes a string as an input and parses it as if it were python code, but does not execute it (making it the "safe" alternative to `eval()`)  This will mean that when you try to add the numbers together you won't get the type error you were getting.  You were getting that type error because python is *strongly typed* (and dynamically typed).  This means that you cannot add a `str` to a `int` and it doesn't automatically convert `int` to a `str` like JavaScript would.

```
import ast

def prizesFunction():
    first  = []
    second = []
    third  = []
    fourth = []

    with open('prizes.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        prizePoints = list(reader)
        first  = [ast.literal_evel(i[0]) for i in prizePoints]
        second = [ast.literal_evel(i[1]) for i in prizePoints]
        third  = [ast.literal_evel(i[2]) for i in prizePoints]
        fourth = [ast.literal_evel(i[3]) for i in prizePoints]

    choice = input('Enter your choice [0-4] : ')
    choice = int(choice)

    if choice == 1:
        return first
    elif choice == 2:
        return second
    elif choice == 3:
        return third
    elif choice == 4:
        return fourth

prize = prizesFunction()
```

Ok, This should help a bit.  Also, doesn't it look nice?  When you are writing python and it starts to look messy... you're probably not doing it pythonically.  `import this`

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great reply again it's much appreciated!  In reference to your 'what are you doing to do here question'  I was trying to get the different prize points from each row, while each column held different prizes for each different run through.  Just tested what you gave me and it seems to work all ok thanks !  When I joined this site I never expected anyone to be quite so helpful as you have been today.  Taking the time to explain things has benefited me immeasurably and it makes me fairly happy that you would take the time to do that !

Comment: Any time.  We're all in this together.

Answer (score 2):

First thing's first, this is python, not C and so you should be using the for loop

```
for prizeWinner in prizeWinners:
```

This eliminates the need for `range()`.  "What if I need to know the index," I hear you ask?  Well, in this case you don't but if you did, the pythonic way is to use `enumerate()`  Like this

```
for ii,prizeWinner in enumerate(prizeWinners):
```

I know this is pedantic, but let's take a look at what this simple change does to your code.

```
def prizeHandout(prizeWinners):
    for prizeWinner in prizeWinners:
        if len(prizeWinners) == 24:
            prizeWinner[2] = (int(prize[0]))
        elif len(prizeWinners) == 12:
            prizeWinner[2] = (int(prize[1]))
        elif len(prizeWinners) == 6:
            prizeWinner[2] = (int(prize[2]))
    print(prizeWinners)
```

Already feels better.
Now, "Prize is a global variable" is already not good.  So we should pass that into the function, and we'll use a default value.
Why are you casting prize as an int?  I'm sure you have a good reason, but if that reason happens to be that you are converting a `str` to an `int` I'd recommend you use [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).  I'm removing it, because it doesn't have any context on the rest of your question.
As far as adding the prize to the prizeWinner[2], let's make that change.

```
def prizeHandout(prizeWinners, prize=[10,20,30]):
    for prizeWinner in prizeWinners:
        if len(prizeWinners) == 24:
            prizeWinner[2] += prize[0]
        elif len(prizeWinners) == 12:
            prizeWinner[2] += prize[1]
        elif len(prizeWinners) == 6:
            prizeWinner[2] += prize[2]
    print(prizeWinners)
```

What I cannot answer from your program is why you are determining prizes by the len(prizeWinners)?  What I imagine you were trying to do is see what index in the array they were.  So, this is where that `enumerate()` would be handy.  Try this on for size; this will increment the prizeWinner[2] by 10 if they are 25th in from the front of the list of prizeWinners, 20 if they are 13th, and 30 if they are 7th.

```
def prizeHandout(prizeWinners, prize=[10,20,30]):
    for ii, prizeWinner in enumerate(prizeWinners):
        if   ii == 24:
            prizeWinner[2] += prize[0]
        elif ii == 12:
            prizeWinner[2] += prize[1]
        elif ii == 6:
            prizeWinner[2] += prize[2]
    print(prizeWinners)
```

That's all I can say on this.  I hope you can follow my steps.

Comment: Hi there VoNWooDSoN, first all thank you so much for your comprehensive answer.  The information that you gave me is exactly the kind of thing I need to help me further my learning !  I've implemented the code that you kindly provided and I am still getting the 'TypeError' that i mentioned in a comment above.  I have edited my original question to include more what I was trying to do.  Understandably, you have already helped alot but do you know the cause of this error?  Thanks !